# FIFA app image transition effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I noticed a beautiful transition between images in the [FIFA Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fifa.fifaapp.android)
, at the explore FIFA section the images appear to be cropped diagonally so that the previous and next images can be seen at the corners with the main image showing at the middle.

here's a link for an image
http://s28.postimg.org/e5h0lcifx/image.png

how to implement such effect and can it be done with a viewpager or i have to do it with a framelayout ?

Comment: Maybe post some screenshots which show what you exactly mean (The diagonal cropping and sliding)

Comment: updated with a link for an image

Comment: so draw two images: a new one as it is and the current clipped with canvas.clipPath()

Comment: I know the guy who did the FIFA app and he told me that it's a heavily modified version of https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax . Good luck.